# Anchor href codebehind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set the href from codebehind for a collapse javascript function but the code is adding "../" before the href and it is not working. How can I make it not add that? I need the ID and HREF matching for it to work. TY!

```
HtmlAnchor BtnCollapse = new HtmlAnchor();
BtnCollapse.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-primary");
BtnCollapse.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "collapse");
BtnCollapse.InnerHtml = "Collapse";
BtnCollapse.Attributes.Add("href", "#MasterPagePlaceholder_collapseExample"+i);            
BtnCollapse.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "collapse");
DivCol0.Controls.Add(BtnCollapse);

HtmlGenericControl DivCollapse = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
DivCollapse.ID = "collapseExample"+i;
DivCollapse.Attributes.Add("class", "collapse");
ctrl1.Controls.Add(DivCollapse);
```

Console View

[image: Console View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your exact code and for me it generates an href attribute without the ../ part.

Maybe you can try and replace the HtmlAnchor with a HyperLink control. It will generate the same output.
Like this:

```
HyperLink BtnCollapse = new HyperLink();
BtnCollapse.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-primary");
BtnCollapse.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "collapse");
BtnCollapse.Text = "Collapse";
BtnCollapse.NavigateUrl = "#MasterPagePlaceholder_collapseExample" + i;
BtnCollapse.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "collapse");
```

Comment: With the change for HyperLink it works, thank you very much. No ideia why the HtmlAncher isn't working for me.